# Processing: PAppletClass causes loop, thus makes alpha dark

Tags: loops, processing, draw, shapes, frames

I'm using processing, just for test purposes in a trainings program.

When I use fill(alpha) it becomes dark the more frames there are, since (I assume) Processing creates more and more of the shapes, overlapping everytime a bit more. 
After executing draw() it goes back to PApplet and then back to draw() again.

Can I tell Programming to only execute draw() once without inventing some weird bypass?

[image: half circles supposed to overlap on the edges]

```java
 public void draw(){

    int winkel=0;
    translate(300,300);
    fill(150, 15);

    for (int i =0;i<8;i++){

        rotate(radians(winkel));
       kreisschnitt(100,0,200,200,0, PI);
       winkel=winkel+45;
    }
}

public void kreisschnitt(int x, int y, int breite, int hoehe,float anfang, float ende){
    noStroke();

    arc(x,y,breite,hoehe,anfang,ende);

}
```

IDEA 2018.2
Java 8

Comment: Found it myself. draw() will loop the inside code until noLoop() is called or program is forced to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `draw()` loop is called 60 times per second by default.

You can disable this by calling `noLoop()` which stops calling `draw()` until you call `loop()` again.

Or you could move all of your code inside the `setup()` function, which is only called once.

For simple sketches, you can get rid of all of your functions and write your code directly, like this:

```
size(500, 500);
background(32);
ellipse(250, 250, 100, 100);
```

Comment: @pikkuez You're welcome. Note that if an answer helped you, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so your question stops showing up as needing an answer.